# call_usermodehelper doesn't work properly

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I work on a kernel module for write something in a file with python from kernel space.
**First Try**: I write this code for run python file from kernel:

```
int ret = -1;    
char path[] = "/bin/bash";
char *argv[] = {path, "-c", "python", "/home/samba/getter.py",NULL};
char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "TERM=linux", "PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin", NULL};

printk("call_usermodehelper module is starting..!\n");
ret = call_usermodehelper(path, argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
printk("ret=%d\n", ret);
```

here is the python code:

```
# getter.py
import urllib2
import json

url = "http://172.16.189.1:8000/random/"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
input_file = open("/home/samba/something.txt", "w")
input_file.write(json.loads(response.read())["hash"])
input_file.close()
```

(above python script works fine. when I run it from user-space it creates `something.txt` file and successfully saves the output.)

after load above module the file `something.txt` doesn't create and when I run `dmesg` command I see this:

```
[16184.383282] call_usermodehelper module is starting..!
[16184.384389] ret=0
```

**second Try**: I change the `python` command to `touch` and still can't create the file but the `ret` value after call touch is non-zero !

```
int ret = -1;    
char path[] = "/bin/bash";
char *argv[] = {path, "-c", "touch", "/home/samba/something.txt",NULL};
char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "TERM=linux", "PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin", NULL};

printk("call_usermodehelper module is starting..!\n");
ret = call_usermodehelper(path, argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
printk("ret=%d\n", ret);
```

when I run `dmeseg` command after loading the module I see the output like this:

```
[16211.309975] call_usermodehelper module is starting..!
[16211.311053] ret=256
```

but the file `/home/samba/something.txt` is not created. what is I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE** : thanks to one of the answers by changing `UMH_WAIT_PROC` to `UMH_WAIT_EXEC` the `touch` command (second case) now creates the file correctly , but the python code still doesn't work.